# Create Tree from Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, smart-pointers

I'm working on a symbolic calculator. But in order to give a small verifiable example, I broke it down to the following example, which may seem odd at first.

I have a list of points {1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 7} which I iterate through. I read two points in each iteration. 
What I want this code to do is:
**Iteration 1:** There is no tree, so we create one. We keep a reference on the 4.

```
  4
 /
1
```

**Iteration 2:** 8 is bigger than last reference (4). So we make

```
  8
 /
3
```

a right child of 4 and keep a reference on 8

```
    4
  /   \
 1      8
       /
      3
```

**Iteration 3:** 7 is smaller than the last reference (8) so we go back up until we find smaller number than 4 (or reach the root). We then create the node

```
 7
  \
   5
```

And add the last reference as left child to this.

```
     7
   /   \
  4      5
 /  \
1    8
    /
   3
```

**Please note: I'm not concerned with special cases etc. here. I'm positive I can figure this out on my own, once I got this working.**

Here is my tree class:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <memory>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class Node : public std::enable_shared_from_this< Node<T> >{
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr< Node<T> > NodePtr;
        typedef std::weak_ptr< Node<T> > NodeWPtr;

        T data;
        NodePtr left, right;
        NodeWPtr parent;

        Node(){}
        Node(const T& data) : data(data){}
        Node(const T& data, NodeWPtr parent) : data(data), parent(parent){}
        Node(const T& data, NodeWPtr parent, NodePtr& left) : data(data), parent(parent), left(left){
            left->parent = this->shared_from_this();
        }
        Node(const Node& n) : data(n.data), left(n.left), right(n.right){}
        Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;
        ~Node() = default;

        NodePtr findRoot(){
            if( parent.lock() ){
                return parent.lock()->findRoot();
            }
            return this->shared_from_this();
        }

        void print(int indent=0){
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::string(2*indent+2, '-') << "L: ";
            if( left ){
                left->print(indent+1);
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::string(2*indent+2, '-') << "R: ";
            if( right ){
                right->print(indent+1);
            }
            if( indent==0 ) std::cout << std::endl;
        }
};

#endif // NODE_H
```

And here my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Node.h"

int main(){
    typedef std::shared_ptr< Node<int> > NodePtr;
    NodePtr last;
    std::vector<int> list {1, 4, 3, 8, 5, 7};
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2 ){
        if( !last ){
            last = std::make_shared< Node<int> >(Node<int>(list.at(i+1)));
            last->left = std::make_shared< Node<int> >(Node<int>(list.at(i), last));
            continue;
        }
        if( list.at(i+1) >= last->data ){
            NodePtr newNode = std::make_shared< Node<int> >(Node<int>(list.at(i+1)));
            newNode->left = std::make_shared< Node<int> >(Node<int>(list.at(i)));
            last->right = newNode;
            newNode->parent = last;
            newNode->findRoot()->print();
            last = newNode;
            last->findRoot()->print();
        }else{
            while( !last->parent.expired() && last->data < list.at(i+1) ){
                last = last->parent.lock();
            }
            NodePtr newNode = std::make_shared< Node<int> >(Node<int>(list.at(i+1)));
            newNode->right = std::make_shared< Node<int> >(Node<int>(list.at(i)));
            newNode->left = last;
            last->parent = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
    }
    last->findRoot()->print();
}
```

Somehow the 4-1 branch gets deleted, when I copy it in the 2nd iteration. It's still there in the first print, but after the copy, it's gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in these following line

```
newNode->parent = last;
newNode->findRoot()->print();
last = newNode;
```

Initially, only shared_ptr `last` points to node 4. After you assign `newNode` to `last`, there is no shared_ptr pointing to node 4 anymore. This leads to weak_ptr `parent` in node 8 expired. Therefore when you call `last->findRoot()` (last here is node 8), it failed to return node 4.

Your data structure ensures that every nodes not except the root one pointed by at least 1 shared_ptr (its parent). So you need to manually keep a shared_ptr to root node.

Comment: Oh, is this because parent is a weak_ptr? I kinda assumed, that it still points to 4 so I'd be safe here

Comment: Yes, weak_ptr does not extend object lifetime.